# Do candidates receive pings from comments under their nominations?

Tags: support, election, notifications

On the page with [moderator candidates nomination](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/5?tab=nomination) it is possible to leave a comment for a candidate. In some cases, quite relevant questions have been asked in the comments and there have been no response from the said candidate. (Of course, they might have decided that there is no need to respond.)

> I would like to know whether the candidate receives some kind of notification about comment under their notification post.

(I agree that candidates probably should check at least occasionally whether there are some new comments. On the other hand, I don't want to them to check obsessively the nominations page and every election-related discussion on meta and in chat twice in a hour. I think they have better things to do - I think that running for a moderator can be time-consuming enough already without that. For example, writing good answers for the questions from the questionnaire will definitely take soemt ime.)

Comment: Only one way to know. Nominate yourself, and I'll leave a comment.

Comment: It has already been said that posting nominations which are not meant seriously - in this case just to carry out an experiment about comments - is frowned upon. (And that is definitely not *the one and only* way to know.

Comment: @Martin: Then post a _serious_ nomination.

Comment: Pretty sure I remember getting pings during mine.

Comment: @Alexander: You're not helping things... ;-)

Comment: Yes pings are received.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user [Dustin](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/78317/dustin), who is a nominee, in [a comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17677/do-candidates-receive-pings-from-comments-under-their-nominations#comment67036_17677), confirmed that **pings are received.**

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this answer in regards to

---

> I agree that candidates probably should check at least occasionally whether there are some new comments. On the other hand, I don't want to them to check obsessively the nominations page and every election-related discussion on meta and in chat twice in a hour.

---

I feel if a member is going to take the time to comment, they deserve to be addressed. That is, anyone who comments to me I will answer you. I think that should be standard for everyone who is nominated since the users' commenting took the time to read your nomination, read some other posts or two of yours, and potentially look at your SX profile. If they are willing to make a time commitment, so to can I.

However, I rarely check the chat.